# SPARQL returning empty result when passing MIN(?date1) from subquery into outer query, with BIND((YEAR(?minDate) - YEAR(?date2)) AS ?diffDate)

Tags: sparql

<This question is now resolved, see comment by Valerio Cocchi>

I am trying to pass a variable from a subquery, that takes the minimum date of a set of dates ?date1 belonging to ?p and passes this to the outer query, which then takes another date ?date2 belonging to ?p (there can be at most 1 ?date2 for every ?p) and subtracts ?minDate from ?date2 to get an integer value for the number of years between. I am getting a blank value for this, i.e. ?diffDate returns no value.

I am using Fuseki version 4.3.2. Here is an example of the query:

```
SELECT ?p ?minDate ?date2 ?diffDate 
  {        
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasAnotherDate ?date2.      
    BIND((YEAR(?minDate) - YEAR(?date2)) AS ?diffDate)      
  {
  SELECT ?p (MIN(?date1) as ?minDate) 
  WHERE 
  { 
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasDate ?date1. 

  } group by ?p 
    }                                 
  }
```

and an example of the kind of result I am getting:

|-?p----|-----------------?minDate-------------|-----------------?date2-------------         |?diffDate|

|<123>|20012-11-22T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime|2008-08-18T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime|   |

I would expect that ?diffDate would give me an integer value.  Am I missing something fundamental about how subqueries work in SPARQL?

Comment: did you try to put the `BIND` after the subquery? For `BIND` the order matters, it will be evaluated before the subquery has been evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have encountered quite an obscure part of the SPARQL spec, namely how `BIND` works.

Normally SPARQL is evaluated without regard for the position of atoms, i.e.

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?a :p1 ?b .
?b :p2 ?c .}
```

is the same query as:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?b :p2 ?c .
?a :p1 ?b .}
```

However, BIND *is* position dependent, so e.g.:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?a :p1 ?b .
BIND(:john AS ?a)}
```

is not a valid query, whereas:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
BIND(:john AS ?a)
?a :p1 ?b .
}
```

is entirely valid. The same applies to variables used inside of the `BIND`, which must be declared before the `BIND` appears.
See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#variableScope) for more.

To go back to your problem, your `BIND` is using the `?minDate` variable before it has been bound, which is why it fails to produce a value for `?diffDate`.

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT ?p ?minDate ?date2 ?diffDate 
  {        
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasAnotherDate ?date2.      
       
  {
  SELECT ?p (MIN(?date1) as ?minDate) 
  WHERE 
  { 
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasDate ?date1. 

  } group by ?p 
    }
BIND((YEAR(?minDate) - YEAR(?date2)) AS ?diffDate)   #Put the BIND after all the variables it uses are bound.
                             
  }
```

Alternatively, you could evaluate the difference in the `SELECT`, like so:

```
SELECT ?p ?minDate ?date2 (YEAR(?minDate) - YEAR(?date2) AS ?diffDate)
  {        
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasAnotherDate ?date2.      

  {
  SELECT ?p (MIN(?date1) as ?minDate) 
  WHERE 
  { 
  ?p a abc:P;
    abc:hasDate ?date1. 

  } group by ?p 
    }

  }
```